# How to dynamically add arguments to class initialization?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, initialization

I have a main class and further classes that are extensions of the main class. The main class has two parameters in its **init** and each of the child classes also uses these parameters + individual parameters

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

class Child1(Main):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(var1, var2)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4

class Child2(Main):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(var1, var2)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.var5 = var5
```

I want to be able to initialize the child classes iteratively by passing actual values such as `Child1(var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3, var4 = 4)` and `Child2(var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var5 = 5)` but without actually having to type them out manually. Ideally I could iterate over a dictionary that stores the values like this:

```
my_dict = {'Child1': {'var3': 3, 'var4': 4}, 'Child2': {'var5': 5}}
```

Note that I only want to pass the class specific variables like this. In the end, I would like to have something like this:

```
var1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var2 = [1, 2]
for x,y, (k,v) in product(var1, var2, my_dict.items()):
    v(var1 = x, var2 = y, $fill missing keyword arguments in here that are specific to child class$)
```

Comment: If you find yourself looking for forceful solutions like this for a problem you're almost always better reconsidering your design instead. This sounds like you're likely abusing inheritance where you should be using composition.

Comment: @Woodford I am open to any suggestions if you have any. How would I change it to composition?

Comment: There's no way to tell from your post. You've only described *what* you want to do, not *why*.

Comment: Well I want to be able to initialize all the child classes so I can call them later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this myself. I was able to use unpacking on my_dict to dynamically fill in the missing arguments.

```
**for x,y, (k,v) in product(var1, var2, my_dict.items()):
    v(var1 = x, var2 = y, **v)
```